# How to use SSH keys with Jenkins Workflow Plugin

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins, ssh-keys, jenkins-workflow

Have a groovy script that's executed by the [Jenkins Worflow Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin).

As [documented](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/scm-step/README.md#built-in-integrations), the git step has only basic configuration so far, having only a single url parameter, and it's [suggested](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/scm-step/README.md#generic-scm-step) to use the general checkout scm step for anything more complex.

With this, it's possible to pass credentialsId as so:

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'MercurialSCM', source: 'ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/repo', clean: true, credentialsId: '1234-5678-abcd']
```

But how would one get this to work with an SSH key credentials instead?

Answer (score 2):

The same syntax should work for SSH private key credentials.

By the way as of [1.4](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/CHANGES.md#14-mar-16-2015) you can pass `credentialsId` to the simple `git` step.

Also if you update the SSH Credentials plugin you can also choose a human-readable ID (when creating a new credentials item).

Comment: Absolutely, I myself am glad I found this. Make note that the JIRA issue displays the `credentialsId` being passed without quotes. You need to make sure to pass quotes (single, I suppose) to ensure that it works, like so `git url: 'ssh://git@repourl/project.git', credentialsId: 'someIDHere'`, otherwise your build with fail with a stacktrace.