# How to checkout ssh remote in github organization Jenkins workflow and use ssh credentials in Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-organizations

I have a `Github Organisation` item in jenkins. On the root of my repository, my `Jenkinsfile` looks something like this:

```groovy
node {

  def jenkinsCredsId = 'xxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbb'

  stage 'Checkout'
  checkout scm
  // I also tried the following:
  // checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', source: 'ssh://git@github.com:MY_ORGANISATION/jenkins-testing-temp.git', clean: true, credentialsId: jenkinsCredsId]

  stage 'Build'
  // generate some artefact (dist.zip)

  stage 'Release'

  sshagent([jenkinsCredsId]) {
    sh '''
    git remote -v // show remotes
    ssh-add -l // show currently loaded ssh keys fingerprints

    git fetch --all --tags // IT FAILS HERE

    CURRENT_BUILD_TAG="some_build/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    git tag ${CURRENT_BUILD_TAG}

    git push --tags

    github-release release \
    --security-token ${GITHUB_RELEASE_TOKEN} \
    --user MY_ORGANIZATION \
    --repo MY_REPO \
    --tag ${CURRENT_BUILD_TAG} \
    --name ${CURRENT_BUILD_TAG}

    github-release upload \
    --security-token ${GITHUB_RELEASE_TOKEN} \
    --user MY_ORGANIZATION \
    --repo MY_REPO \
    --tag ${CURRENT_BUILD_TAG} \
    --name ${CURRENT_BUILD_TAG} \
    --file dist.zip
    '''
  }
```

There's a few lines for testing repository access in here and **it's currently failing on the `git fetch` part** with the following error:

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

The `git remote -v` command from the above `Jenkinsfile` outputs something like `origin https://github.com/MY_ORGANIZATION/MY_REPO`.

My `Github Organization` git configuration looks like this:
[image: repository-sources-github-organization-jenkins-config]

I found a few related questions:

- [how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-jenkins-workflow-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632566/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-jenkins-workflow-plugin)
- [tag-a-repo-from-a-jenkins-workflow-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570075/tag-a-repo-from-a-jenkins-workflow-script)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that the `Github Organization` item only uses https credentials for the `Scan credentials` (like the picture above).

The solution was to hit `Advanced` button, and to actually select a `ssh` credential in the `Checkout credentials` dropdown instead of the default `- Same as scan credentials -`.

[image: advanced-view-checkout-credentials]

Note that credentials with stars are user/password entries, that's how I found the problem.

This way, the `checkout scm` will use ssh instead and the `sshagent([jenkinsCredsId]) {` block will work as expected, letting you create tags, fetch and push according to your rights. :)